# How to add listener on a button in a notification (custom layout)

Tags: android, button, notifications, listener

I have a notification layout which is something like this:

[image: Notification screenshot]

My service is **ongoing**. I want a notification/event sent to my service when stop button is pressed. Click event on notification view is not required.

When the button is pressed, I want my service to stop.

Currently, I'm trying to do this by sending broadcast to an activity (as I did not find a way to directly inform service of the button press).

My current code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MediaEventsReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnStop, pending);
```

I've also added the reciver in my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".activities.SplashActivity$MediaEventsReceiver" />
```

Please use code example(s) to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I've used another activity which is called on button click by PendingIntent.
The new activity binds the service and sends it a stop message.
Right after it, it unbinds itself and finishes.

**STILL:**

I want a solution which does not involve a third activity. There SHOULD be a way where the button click in notification directly informs service and service stops itself. There is NO NEED of an activity for this task.

Comment: Nops. I did it the way I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

I'm developing a music player app using SINGLE activity. You can add listener to your button like this:

1. Bind intent

`Intent intent = new Intent("ACTION_NAME");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.previousImageView, pendingIntent);`

2. Implement a custom BroadcastReceiver

`private class ActionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            switch (intent.getAction())
            {
                case "ACTION_NAME":
                {
                    doSomething();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }`

3. Register your BroadcastReceiver

`IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction("ACTION_NAME");
 ActionBroadcastReceiver actionBroadcastReceiver = new ActionBroadcastReceiver();
 registerReceiver(actionBroadcastReceiver, filter);`